# Is there are a replacement for the CONVERT function in sql (SMSS) to a similar function in Pyspark.sql. In other words is there a similar function?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

For the SELECT STATEMENT BELOW:

```
select ( Cast (( Cast(T1.partition_ AS VARCHAR(21)) + '|' 
              + T1.dataareaid_ + '|' 
              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), T1.ledgertransdate, 112) ) AS VARCHAR(255)) )     AS FKDATEFINANCIAL
FROM TABLE;
```

When I try to execute the above sql statement in pyspark.sql using SqlContext, I get the following error:
**AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'CONVERT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;**

In other words,
"CONVERT" is a SQL Server function, What is the equivalent of it in Spark SQL?

Comment: Can you please share the desired output?

Comment: I believe using `CONCAT` and `CAST` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The convert function is a method in sqlserver you can just use cast and it will do the same job

Comment: Thanks! this works for me!